# How to disable horizontal scrolling on a website for iOS (CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I can't seem to be able to disable horizontal scrolling in CSS for iOS. I need the extra width on the side to make room for my navbar so it is essential for me to disable it.

I've tried

```
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

But I can still scroll horizontally on my iPhone
Code should be up at https://infinity6542.netlify.app

Comment: Could you put up a runnable snippet so it is easy for us to observe this on IOS. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and please check that the snippet does show the problem when run.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
*{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I believe *overflow* attribute is enough.